# Overwrite previous user inputted variable with new user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a calculator, and I'm a bit stuck on how to overwrite the user input with a new value using the same variable. What I am wanting is when greeted at the menu, when the user enters "5" it prompts for a new input for the variables "num1" and "num2". I have a feeling this is extremely easy to do but for some reason i'm stuck.

I have tried the normal - `num1 = int(input("Enter new first number: ))` and so on within the correct elif, but I get:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num1' referenced before assignment

Here is my code:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))


def calculate():

    print('''The numbers you have selected to calculate are: 
    {}, and {} \n'''.format(num1, num2))

    menu = int(input(''' Main Menu:
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction 
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Enter new numbers
    6. Exit\n '''))

    if menu == 1:
        add = addition(num1, num2)
        print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, add))
    elif menu == 2:
        sub = subtract(num1, num2)
        print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1, num2, sub))
    elif menu == 3:
        multi = multiply(num1, num2)
        print("{} x {} = {}".format(num1, num2, multi))
    elif menu == 4:
        div = divide(num1, num2)
        print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, div))
    elif menu == 5:
        num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    elif menu == 6:
        print("Exiting...")
    else:
        print("You have not entered a valid input.")

    rerun()
```

Comment: i have a feeling there is no way to do this unless you do num1 and num2 as lists but just wondering if theres a way to do it without having to use lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `num1` and `num2` variables are not defined inside the function `calculate`. So, when you try to access `num1` inside the function, it will throw an error.

```
def calculate():
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

    print('''The numbers you have selected to calculate are: 
    {}, and {} \n'''.format(num1, num2))

    menu = int(input(''' Main Menu:
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction 
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Enter new numbers
    6. Exit\n '''))

    if menu == 1:
        add = addition(num1, num2)
        print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, add))
    elif menu == 2:
        sub = subtract(num1, num2)
        print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1, num2, sub))
    elif menu == 3:
        multi = multiply(num1, num2)
        print("{} x {} = {}".format(num1, num2, multi))
    elif menu == 4:
        div = divide(num1, num2)
        print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, div))
    elif menu == 5:
        num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    elif menu == 6:
        print("Exiting...")
    else:
        print("You have not entered a valid input.")

    rerun()

calculate()
```

You can also try and make the variables `num1` and `num2` global.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))


def calculate():
    global num1, num2
    print('''The numbers you have selected to calculate are: 
    {}, and {} \n'''.format(num1, num2))

    menu = int(input(''' Main Menu:
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction 
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Enter new numbers
    6. Exit\n '''))

    if menu == 1:
        add = addition(num1, num2)
        print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, add))
    elif menu == 2:
        sub = subtract(num1, num2)
        print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1, num2, sub))
    elif menu == 3:
        multi = multiply(num1, num2)
        print("{} x {} = {}".format(num1, num2, multi))
    elif menu == 4:
        div = divide(num1, num2)
        print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, div))
    elif menu == 5:
        num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    elif menu == 6:
        print("Exiting...")
    else:
        print("You have not entered a valid input.")

    rerun()

calculate()
```

You could also pass the variables as parameters to the function `calculate`

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

```
def calculate(num1, num2):
    print('''The numbers you have selected to calculate are: 
    {}, and {} \n'''.format(num1, num2))

    menu = int(input(''' Main Menu:
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction 
    3. Multiplication
    4. Division
    5. Enter new numbers
    6. Exit\n '''))

    if menu == 1:
        add = addition(num1, num2)
        print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, add))
    elif menu == 2:
        sub = subtract(num1, num2)
        print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1, num2, sub))
    elif menu == 3:
        multi = multiply(num1, num2)
        print("{} x {} = {}".format(num1, num2, multi))
    elif menu == 4:
        div = divide(num1, num2)
        print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1, num2, div))
    elif menu == 5:
        num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    elif menu == 6:
        print("Exiting...")
    else:
        print("You have not entered a valid input.")

    rerun()

calculate(num1, num2)
```

Comment: Had no clue something like "global" existed - it worked perfectly! thank you